# How can I change Text size

Tags: python, text, qt5, size

```
def show_winner():
    rn = randint(1,10)
    winner.setText(str(rn))
    text.setText("Winner")
```

#How can i give size to (text)

Answer (score 0):

```
f = texteditor1.font()
f.setPointSize(27) # sets the size to 27
texteditor1.setFont(f)
```